# ImportError: cannot import name 'IsolationForest'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers

When executing the import

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
```

Getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-13-90a3d865c881>", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

ImportError: cannot import name 'IsolationForest'
```

Any idea what could be the issue ?

Comment: Error is clear, this was introduced in version `0.18` so what version are you running?

Comment: Got resolved by update "conda update scikit-learn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the command:

pip install -U sklearn

this step to update your sklearn(<0.18,maybe 0,17) to sklearn(0.18)